# Jgit find Ref of the commit

Tags: jgit

I am trying to write a jgit code to find all associated branches(Refs) based on a commit. The Idea is basically to call nameRev with addPrefix and pass head, remote and tag as params to find all branches.

```
Iterable<RevCommit> commits = repositoryBrowser.getLatestGitCommits(4);

        for (RevCommit commit : commits) {

            Map<ObjectId, String> branch= new Git(repository).nameRev().add(commit.toObjectId()).call();
            log(commit.getShortMessage() + "\tbranch: " + ss);
        }
```

Output of the above is as under:

`Release 2.3.2 from xxxxxxx    branch: {AnyObjectId[3533e4063644c0436ac5e873a75b647703aea6dd]=v2.3.2}`

The problem is that for the first commit, branch points to a tag (refs/tags/v2.3.2). It is hard to imagine a commit which does not belongs to any branch and just to a tag.

I am a bit confused, is my approach right or am I doing something wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It makes no difference if a branch points to a tag pointing to a specific commit or a tag pointing to that commit. Or do you think of annotated tags?

Comment: Your code snippet does not include a call to `addPrefix`, not sure what the default is. Did you try to add just the prefixes you are looking for?